# Logarithm expansion

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have a problem showing that the following identity for power series holds true:

$$
\ln(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$

when $\left|x\right|<1$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance,

Kijn

Comment: Use the geometric series fromula and differentiate the LHS, then expand out as a series, then integrate again but term-by-term.

Comment: @anon: Expansion of which series, please?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora The expansion of the *expression* you get on the LHS after you wrap up $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ with the geometric series formula and then differentiate. The expression one obtains should look familiar to anyone following my instructions, so will be easy to expand.

Comment: @anon: using the geometric series formula I get $-log(1-x)$ on the LHS, so the expansion (of $log(1+x)$)directly gives me the RHS without differentiating and integrating as you say...

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora It's not clear to me the OP knows how to expand $\log$ $-$ if they did, they might not have posted this question to begin with. My instructions to the OP make clear one only needs to know how to expand the geo series.

Answer (score 3):

When $|x|<1$, the series $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ converges and is equal to 
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}\tag{1}$$
Integrate this expansion, you get
$$\frac x1+\frac{x^2}2+\cdots=-\ln(1-x)\tag{2}$$
Combining (1) in the logarithm, you get 
$$\ln(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=\ln\frac1{1-x}=-\ln(1-x)=\frac x1+\frac{x^2}2+\cdots$$
where the last equality has been obtained using (2).